# Java version configuration with Hadoop helloworld and non-generic Iterator

Tags: hadoop, javac, rhel

I am working on a RHEL Intel cluster that has had hadoop already installed and heavily used and tested by other users.  I am trying to learn to use the framework, so I am starting with the tutorial here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/mapred_tutorial.html

So, I copied the source code of WordCount.java from the above link into ~/hadooptest/, and followed the instructions for compilation with some minor changes to fix version errors, and here is the output of the compilation attempt as well as some relevant system information.

```
[X@X hadooptest]$ pwd
/home/X/hadooptest
[X@X hadooptest]$ javac -version
Eclipse Java Compiler v_677_R32x, 3.2.1 release, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2006. All rights reserved.
[X@X hadooptest]$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
[X@X hadooptest]$ hadoop version
Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u5
Subversion file:///data/1/tmp/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u5 -r 30233064aaf5f2492bc687d61d72956876102109
Compiled by root on Fri Oct  5 18:45:42 PDT 2012
From source with checksum de1770d69aa93107a133657faa8ef467
[X@X hadooptest]$ javac -source 5.0 -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar -d wordcount_classes/ WordCount.java
----------
1. ERROR in WordCount.java (at line 0)
    package org.myorg;
    ^
The type Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <V2>
----------
2. ERROR in WordCount.java (at line 29)
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                 ^^^^^^^^
The type Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <IntWritable>
----------
2 problems (2 errors)[X@X hadooptest]$
```

I understand that this problem is probably not particular to Hadoop, but I'm not primarily a Java user.  When I get comfortable with doing it using Hadoop's native language I will probably choose to switch to using the C++ library (but that's a story for another day).  I have googled this problem and I find that it is typically indicative of using a 1.4.X JRE...Which we do also have:

```
[fraha1@intel06 hadooptest]$ java -version
java version "1.4.2"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)

Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[fraha1@intel06 hadooptest]$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

I've set up ~/.bash_profile to direct to the 1.6 JRE, but presumably javac is configured to still redirect to the default 1.4.  How can I fix this?

Comment: So you are compiling for Java5 and running on a Java4 JVM? Why don't you take the wordcount example from the examples jar?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, when you say I'm running a Java4 JVM, are you saying that based on the line `gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)`?  When I actually run it, I will be using the 1.6 JRE defined in $JAVA_HOME.  And as far as the example, what jar are you referring to?  Mine is identical to the source code posted on the website I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got a mess with your Java environment configuration.

If you got the command `alternatives` installed (if not install it) in your system, you can easily handling your different Java installations. Just type:

```
$ alternatives --config java

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java
*  2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/bin/java
 + 3           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java
```

And select which java would you like to run by default.

This solves the java issue.

Then your `javac` is not pointing to $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac. Try to compile the example as:

```
   $ $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -source 5.0 \
-classpath /usr/lib/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar \
-d wordcount_classes/ WordCount.java
```

This should work.